# Memory leak, spring 3.2.0.RELEASE, httpcomponents 4.2.3

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

Using spring 3.2.0.RELEASE resttemplate & httpcomponents 4.2.3 to make rest calls. Memory footprint is steadily increasing until it reaches max.

Following is the configuration:

```
<bean id="myRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <bean factory-bean="httpClient" factory-method="get"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="httpClient" class="com.mycompany.myproject.common.rest.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="myKeyserverCA" ></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${com.mycompany.myproject.security.client.keyPassword}" ></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="${default.max.total.connections}" ></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="${default.max.host.connections}" ></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="myKeyserverCA"
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:${com.mycompany.myproject.security.client.keyStore}" />
    <property name="password" value="${com.mycompany.myproject.security.client.keyStorePass}" />
</bean>
```

HttpClient:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class HttpClient {

private static final int DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = (60 * 1000);

private KeyStore keystore;
private String password;
private int MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION;
private int MAX_PER_ROUTE;

public HttpClient(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword, int MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION, int MAX_PER_ROUTE) {
    this.keystore = keyStore;
    this.password = keyPassword;
    this.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION = MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION;
    this.MAX_PER_ROUTE = MAX_PER_ROUTE;
}

public org.apache.http.client.HttpClient get() {
    PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(getSchemeRegistry(this.keystore, this.password));
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_PER_ROUTE);
    connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();

    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager);
    httpClient.getParams().setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    return httpClient;
}

private static SchemeRegistry getSchemeRegistry(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword) {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    try{
        TrustManager[] trustManagerArray = { new TautologicalX509TrustManager() };
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, keyPassword.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerArray, null);
                    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslc, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                    registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, sslSocketFactory));
        return registry;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

TautologicalX509TrustManager:

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class TautologicalX509TrustManager  implements X509TrustManager {

private static final X509Certificate[] EMPTY_CERTIFICATES = new X509Certificate [0];

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
    throws CertificateException {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
        throws CertificateException {
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return EMPTY_CERTIFICATES;
}



}
```

After running load tests on this component, we see lot of SSLSocketImpl objects and byte[].
Incoming references to SSLSocketImpl are from Finalizer object.

When we do netstat on the machine after load test is stopped, we dont see any open tcp connections to underlying services. During the load test however, there are many many connections in TIME_WAIT state and few in ESTABLISHED state but all of them are closed after test is stopped.

Are we missing any API call to close sockets? Why do we have so many SSLSocketImpl objects hanging around in our heap?

Comment: If we just make http calls to underlying services instead of https, then there is no leak even under heavy load.

Comment: There are about 8000 com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl objects of which only 50 of them are in connectionState 1 or 2. Rest of them are in connectionState 7.

ConnectionStates:
    private static final int    cs_START = 0;
    private static final int    cs_HANDSHAKE = 1;
    private static final int    cs_DATA = 2;
    private static final int    cs_RENEGOTIATE = 3;
    private static final int    cs_ERROR = 4;
    private static final int   cs_SENT_CLOSE = 5;
    private static final int    cs_CLOSED = 6;
    private static final int    cs_APP_CLOSED = 7;

Comment: (7) APP_CLOSED once the application calls close(). Then it behaves like a closed socket, e.g.. getInputStream() throws an Exception.
(2) DATA may be transmitted.
(1) HANDSHAKE picks session parameters before allowing traffic. There are many substates due to sequencing requirements for handshake messages.

Comment: If we run System.gc() [when getting heap-dump] 90% of SSLSocketImpl objects are gc'ed and there is a huge drop in memory footprint, then memory consumption resumes again

Comment: Do you get an OutOfMemory exception or see high CPU consumption for GC?

Comment: We are not running the tests so long that we get OutOfMemory. We saw the memory increasing consistently when we ran for 1 hour. Right around the time when GC resulted in heap memory drop (1.2GB to 300MB), we did not notice any abnormal CPU spike.

Comment: It does not seem to be a memory leak. To confirm, run your tests with minimum memory require (300MB) and see an OOM happens. It seems to me that since the heap size is large, the GC is being delayed.

Comment: You are correct. GC is being delayed. Confirmed that.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late reply but this answer is for future visitors to this question. The reason that you see large volume of `SSLSocketImpl` in your heap and then which gets garbage collected is because `SSLSessionContext` supports caching SSL connections, which can be reused by across distinct TCP connections to reduce handshake overhead when negotiating temporary encryption keys after the actual TCP connection has been established.

By default the `SSLSessionContext` unlimited number of sessions for default  time period of 24 hours, which means that you can end up using lot of heap memory under high traffic. One way is to set cache size that suits your application needs. Here is an example:

`sslContext.getServerSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1000);`